# Patterns and Practices for communication between Web Extensions and a web app

Tags: google-chrome-extension, messaging, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing an extension and I'm a bit stuck about the communication between the web-app, the content-script of the extension, and the communication between the content-script and the background-script. It seems to be that HTML5 Messaging API is to be used, but how to do that in a precise context is not only hard to understand and implement, but also confusing due to differences of approach in Browsers (which seemingly support the same API).

For example, Firefox doesn't recognise the `externally_connectable` in `manifest.json`, which is where one assigns permissions for the hosts where requests originate from. So how does Firefox expect you the developer to assign the permissions? I assume it expects you do that within the content-script?

Particularly, I'm confused about what is the best way to exchange data between the app and the content/background script. Is the best way `postMessage` / `addListener` methods and do they work in all contexts; or as someone mentioned: `window.dispatchEvent` should be preferred?

All guides relevant to the point above are appreciated.

Comment: Use DOM messaging between the web page and content script, use [standard extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) between content script and the background page. No problem.

Comment: Thx. What do you mean with DOM Messaging?

Comment: postMessage and dispatchEvent

Answer (score 2):

Messages coming from outside the extension is not something I have experience with (and I'm not sure that's what you mean).

You should make sure you thoroughly understand the [chrome extensions overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) which is definitely required reading.

re Window.dispatch and using other APIs, my suggestion is stick to the chrome.xxx APIs unless there's something they can't do.

There are 3 scopes potentially in your extension that can only communicate by messaging but the messaging is simple to implement and actually can lead to good designs.

Content scripts are the key to interacting with the page itself but their scope isn't the same as the page, the js is isolated but they can access the DOM of course.

Content scripts can be loaded when every page loads or just some pages by including them in the manifest. Or powerfully, they can be injected by the background page or the popup - so if you're intention is to control from the popup, you can use [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi)  - a useful pattern is that the popup (or background) can launch a url in a tab, inject jquery (any version because it's isolated), then inject the content script, the content script can then use $(document).ready() to wait for the page to be loaded (don't have to use jQuery but the fact that you can without caring whether the page has jQuery or not, or what version it might have) is useful.

If you already knew this much, you might not be as confused as you think :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! However, my struggle mainly is with Firefox rather than Chrome, specifically how I shall register request permissions since it doesn't support `externally_connectable`... I think it requires a certain pattern of communication, and hence my question...